# Xamarin: passing parameters from binding to custom control

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been learning the Xamarin framework lately, and I wanted to create a reusable control element that displays some properties of an object. To remove redundancy, I wanted to pass the complete object to the control and have it manage how to display it. However, I'm encountering strange behaviour when passing it an object from a binding.

Instead of receiving the object instance, it only receives some instance of Xamarin.Forms.internals<TypedBinding<CoffeeCounter.Demo.Page, CoffeeCounter.Demo.Parameter>. I'd either need to extract the instance of the object from this or change something such that the actual instance is already passed.

Here is a compact demo of the problem. First a simple page view, with an instance of the reusable control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:demo="clr-namespace:CoffeeCounter.Demo;assembly=CoffeeCounter"
    x:Class="CoffeeCounter.Demo.Page"
    x:DataType="demo:Page">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <demo:Control Parameter="{Binding Parameter}"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

It receives the parameter object with the properties to display from the code-behind.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CoffeeCounter.Demo {
    public partial class Page : ContentPage {
        public Page() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        public Parameter Parameter => new Parameter{Foo="Football", Bar="Barricade"};
    }
}
```

And the parameter class simply looks like this.

```
namespace CoffeeCounter.Demo {
    public class Parameter {
        public string Foo {get; set;}
        public string Bar {get; set;}
    
        public override string ToString() {
            return "Foo: " + Foo + ", " + "Bar: " + Bar;
        }
    }
}
```

The control is then built like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="CoffeeCounter.Demo.Control">
    <Label x:Name="Title" Text=""/>
</ContentView>
```

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CoffeeCounter.Demo {
    public partial class Control {
        public static readonly BindableProperty PARAMETER = BindableProperty.Create(
            "Parameter",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(Control),
            null,
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => {
                var control = (Control) bindable;
                control.Title.Text = newValue.ToString();
            }
        );

        public object Parameter {
            set => SetValue(PARAMETER, value);
        }
        public Control() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm aware the custom control can probably make use of bindings as well to update its contents, but that's not the point of this question.

Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but there are few errors.

```
    public Page()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this; //add this line
    }

    public Parameter Parameter => new Parameter { Foo = "Football", Bar = "Barricade" };
```

Your Control.Xaml.cs should be like this.

```
    public Control()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Parameter),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(Control),
        null,
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => {
            var control = (Control)bindable;
            control.Title.Text = newValue.ToString();
        }
    );

    public object Parameter
    {
        set => SetValue(ParameterProperty, value);
    }
```

Comment: This works indeed, but the name of the BindableProperty is not directly used anywhere else. Is this implicit naming indeed the only and intended way to do this? Seems odd to me..